# How to ignore certain patterns in a json file?

Tags: json, chatbot

I am using a json file to create a chatbot.
If i type in "good idea!" the Bot responses "No Problem :D".
But I dont want the Bot to respond to this with, "Thats Nice! :D". (The Bot responses with this when die User says he is doing fine/good)

What I want to do, is to type in sentences that the Bot should ignore.

Is this possible?

I tried somethings, but it didnt work...

Comment: Can you focus on one problem? You mention loading from JSON in a bot but in your description you're talking about ignoring bot patterns? I'm a bit confused and I think this question needs more focus.

Comment: Problem is, i dont know how to configure, that the Chatbot ignores certain Patterns